# What Species are Mr. Men and Little Miss creatures by Roger Hargreaves? Are they all the same?

Tags: mr-men, little-miss

When I was I child, I greatly enjoyed the Mr. Men and Little Miss series. As I got older, I learned that there are multiple branded products and even a TV show.
Considering that quite a lot of thought went into this creation, do we ever learn what species these creatures are, and whether they are all the same species or each is a unique one of his own?
[image]

Comment: They're largely *emotions* or *traits*

Comment: Iirc there are humans that look like humans in the books, which suggests the Mr Men themselves aren't humans. I like the question but I'm not optimistic you'll get a sourced answer.

Comment: @WiggotheWookie I recall something similar as well

Comment: We won’t really know unless we breed some, then see if the offspring can breed with each other. Now _that’s_ a TV show.

Comment: Some of them are certainly unique; for example, Mr Snow was a snowman made by normal human children, who was brought to life by Father Christmas' magic. Mr Daydream doesn't exist at all - he's just a figure a boy call Jack was daydreaming about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Mr. Men are '*little bits of human beings*', '*encapsulating human emotions*'

> “That’s the holy grail, to come up with something that’s unique,”
> Hargreaves says. “Whether it’s simple or complex, it’s new and grabs
> everybody’s attention. That’s what my dad managed with the look of the
> Mr Men. He managed to encapsulate human emotions in the simplest form
> that you can imagine.
>
> “There is an innate Britishness to them. The landscapes are very
> British, the interiors equally so, though stuck in the 1970s in terms
> of their interior decor. At the same time, they have a global appeal
> because **they are little bits of human beings.**
>
> <sub><sup>[The past, present and future of Mr Men and Little Miss books as they celebrate their 50th birthday](https://www.bigissue.com/culture/books/the-past-present-and-future-of-mr-men-and-little-miss-books-as-they-celebrate-their-50th-birthday/)</sup></sub>

It's worthy of note that classical humans do also exist in Misterland. [Dr Makeyouwell](https://mrmen.fandom.com/wiki/Dr._Makeyouwell), for example appears in dozens of books and TV shows.

[image]